# iPad freezes and won't turn back on

Tags: ipad, performance, startup

I'm having troubles with my iPad. While using my iPad it suddenly froze and later it shut off altogether even though the battery was 90% charged.

When restarting I looked at the screen and there was a small loading icon but no Apple logo. The loading screen just kept going and the iPad won't turn on.

The catch is, I can't use my restart button because the button is broken. This iPad is also old (probably an iPad 2).

What can I do to try and get it to restart?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you share a picture of the loading screen?

Comment: I would say go to DFU mode and restore the iOS but with the restart broken that's not possible.  This might be the end of its long and glorious life.

Answer (score 1):

If you iPad is currently spinning trying to boot and you don’t have access to the power button there isn’t much you can do at the moment. Hopefully allowing you Device to continue to try to boot will drain the batteries. This will allow your device to shut down, then start charging and hopefully it will boot up. Start charging with your computer so you can tell if your computer is recognizing the device while it’s booting. Going to About my Mac > System Profile > USB will show you if your device is registering with your computer.

If not, and you are comfortable following an ifixit tear down, you could take it apart to see if you can either clean up the power button (it’s probably dirty) or manually press the power-button if the little lever is broken on the button, which you could use for DFU or Recovery.

Search for your models water sensors, usually in the headphone and charging jack to see if there is water damage.

Answer (score 0):

I would try plugging it into your computer to see if it's recognized by iTunes or your computer in general. Outside of that, you'd most likely need to visit an Apple Store or an Apple Authorized Service Provider, as you would most likely need a unit replacement or a button replacement.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a software issue or a combination of software issues. But if the power button could not work it cant be put into recovery mode or DFU mode. Or you couldn't force start it. Did you check it while charging cable attached?
The thing is this device is so old so there are not many things that can be done. So I guess if it does not start its own. Its time to retire it.